# Signup script not inserting users anymore into table, nor allowing logins

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Registering members and allowing them to login (updating tables etc) all worked fine up until I made this change recently. Which essentially said, if this person logs in check if they are member or admin and show them a different page depending on what they are). I manually went into the table and set existing users as a 'member' apart from 1 person who was 'admin'. Now when I try to sign a user up it doesn't insert into the `tblUsers` anymore.

The change I made is below:

```
<?php
    if ($_SESSION['fldUserLevel'] == 'Member'){
?>
    // PAGE DETAILS
<?php
    }
?>
```

^^^ This would show top half of page and then for admin who would see the bottom half of the page:

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION['fldUserLevel'] == 'Admin'){
?>
    // PAGE DETAILS
<?php
    }
?>
```

Since doing this when I sign a user up, the details no longer go into the table, can someone suggest why? Or do I need a script that says all people who sign up, make the `UserLevel` 'Member'?

Code for signing up:

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['signup-submit'])) {

  require 'dbh.inc.php';


  $username = $_POST['uid'];
  $email = $_POST['mail'];
  $password = $_POST['pwd'];
  $passwordRepeat = $_POST['pwd-repeat'];


  // check for any empty inputs. 
  if (empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($passwordRepeat)) {
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=emptyfields&uid=".$username."&mail=".$email);
    exit();
  }
  // check for an invalid username AND invalid e-mail.
  else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username) && !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invaliduidmail");
    exit();
  }
  // check for an invalid username. In this case ONLY letters and numbers.
  else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)) {
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invaliduid&mail=".$email);
    exit();
  }
  // check for an invalid e-mail.
  else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invalidmail&uid=".$username);
    exit();
  }
  // check if the repeated password is NOT the same.
  else if ($password !== $passwordRepeat) {
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=passwordcheck&uid=".$username."&mail=".$email);
    exit();
  }
  else {

    // include another error handler here that checks whether or the username is already taken. We HAVE to do this using prepared statements because it is safer!

    $sql = "SELECT uidUsers FROM tblUsers WHERE uidUsers=?;";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
      header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
      exit();
    }
    else {
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
      $resultCount = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
      mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
      if ($resultCount > 0) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=usertaken&mail=".$email);
        exit();
      }
      else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tblUsers (uidUsers, emailUsers, pwdUsers) VALUES (?, ?, ?);";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
          exit();
        }
        else {
          $hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

          mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $username, $email, $hashedPwd);


          mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

          header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=success");
          exit();

        }
      }
    }
  }
  mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
  mysqli_close($conn);
}
else {
  header("Location: ../signup.php");
  exit();
}
```

Screenshot of webpage saying successful signup:
[Signup Successful Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpZg0.png)

Screenshot of table, which shows no entry of Kayz:
[Screenshot of phpMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zN1U.png)

Comment: How did you set `fldUserLevel` in your database, because if it's set to not being NULL you'll have an issue with your sign-in : you never set `fldUserLevel` in your `INSERT` statement. Don't you have some SQL errors displayed ?

Comment: Hi @RomainB. that's exactly what it is, I think, as I just manually went in to the table for testing to existing members and set those as members myself, how would I add this into my signup statement about saying insert as `Member` in `fldUserLevel`, I think that's why it's not allowing me to sign up anyone

Comment: You should check whether `mysqli_stmt_execute` throws any error through `mysqli_stmt_error` - this will help you to find such errors on your own

Comment: You can modify your query to `"INSERT INTO tblUsers (uidUsers, emailUsers, pwdUsers,fldUserLevel) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);"` or set a default value on your column as everyone seems to be a Member by default : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html

Comment: @NicoHaase where should I paste that `mysqli_stmt_error `?

Comment: Wherever you want to check for errors - the best way would be to check for it directly after executing the query, and write the error along with the query to a log file

Comment: @RomainB. it still didn't like that query, do I perhaps need to say somewhere that I want 'Member' to go into ? for the table  `fldUserLevel` on sign up?

Comment: GOT IT @RomainB. at the top I just said $member = "Member"; and added an extra placeholder just as you suggested!! :)  THANK YOUuuuu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that you have actually set a variable name giving "Member"; or "Admin";, however I would suggest that as Romain.B suggests to read that document on setting default values.

`$member = "Member"; or "Admin";`

Then your query should be:
`$sql = "INSERT INTO tblUsers (uidUsers, emailUsers, pwdUsers, fldUserLevel) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";`

Further down you need to include your new variable of $member:
`mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $username, $email, $hashedPwd, $member);`